# Do only 800K of 6M Muslims work in France?

Tags: france, muslims

Claim that has surfaced in local TV station coverage of French election:

> There are 6 millions of Muslims in France, but only 800 thousands of them work

Are these numbers accurate?

Comment: Can you link to a source of the claim?

Comment: Please avoid any answers based on partial data: Muslims do not live exclusively in banlieues and are not necessarily immigrants.

Comment: does the figure include people who aren't considered employable by usual unemployment statistics definition? (e.g. minors)?

Comment: @user5341 it seems to be the case (e.g. there are 66 million people in france but only 19 million are employed, which seems to be on the same order of magnitude, percentage-wise, 29% instead of 13%), but of course I haven't looked at any specific evidence.

Comment: @Sklivvz: I found 65 million people in the UK in 2015 and 29.8 million employed in the UK in 2013 (employment numbers at https://www.gov.uk/government/news/record-numbers-of-people-in-work-as-employment-rises-by-80000-in-3-months ) and https://www.statista.com/statistics/275310/employment-in-france/ shows 25 million employed in France. I wonder if different countries have different definitions of "employed".

Comment: @SAH being poorer and unfairer? Also - not all value goes through proper employment. Women historically have worked as homemakers and had a huge contribution to a functioning society, but would not be considered "employed" in this argument.

Comment: @gnasher729 yes, countries have different definitions for being employed